# Where can I write concurrent assertion in monitor?

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, uvm, system-verilog-assertions

I have to write the following concurrent assertion in my monitor:

```
assert property (vif.cos == 1 |-> vif_out.y == vif.xi/sqrt(2));
```

I tried to put it in the run_phase, but I got the following error:
Concurrent assertions are not allowed in tasks/class methods.

Where should I put it?

Comment: You could declare a concurrent assertion inside a module, an interface, a program, a clocking block or a package. Please, correct me if there is any other scope that you could declare a concurrent assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf), Section 14.16 (Concurrent assertions).

> A concurrent assertion statement may be specified in any of the following:
>
> - An always procedure or initial procedure as a statement, wherever these procedures may appear
> - A module
> - An interface
> - A program
> - A generate block
> - A checker

Personally, I would just move that piece of code into the interface file.

Answer (score 0):

Concurrent assertions are not allowed in tasks/class methods. You have to put them in a module or similar (interface/program/checker).